# How can I get rid of double downcasting in this example?

Tags: c#

I have the following piece of code:

```
List<object> qIDs = myObject.ExtraData as List<object>; //ExtraData is of type object - Fixed and can't be changed. Old (bad) design.
List<Tuple<string, bool>> itemIds = new List<Tuple<string, bool>>();

foreach (object tuple in qIDs)
{
    itemIds.Add((Tuple<string, bool>)tuple);
}
//do something with itemIds
```

Basically the `myObject.ExtraData` is an `object` which stores a list of tuples `{string, bool}`. But in order to retrieve the `List<Tuple<,>>` I have to downcast twice: once to `List<object>` and the iterate through each element and add it to a `List<Tuple<string, bool>>`. Anyway to get rid of this?

Background/Meta: The need for `List<object>` is part of glorious hack and is currently the only way for the List to contain objects of two different types - a list of tuples and list of some other struct, so as to prevent the code consuming the lists to change for every type of object in the list.

Comment: Instead of that "hack", why not make the methods generic?

Comment: Because the objects don't share any commonality. The list contains objects of two totally unrelated data structures. I can create a marker interface to make them of the same type, but not sure if that'll really help to begin with. Besides, we can't support both. So support for the "older one" will be phased out and for now we must go with this "hack"

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding the background part of your question. ExtraData will contain a List<> but of mixed types? In this case you would need to check each entry is the type you're after before casting in your foreach loop. In this case, could you not change the type of ExtraData from object to List<object>?

Comment: @Eraph - Unfortunately no. Other classes depend on `ExtraData` being an object and they downcast accordingly. This is an artifact of bad design and I have to work with this constraint.

Comment: Understood. As long as it is expected to contain mixed contents, I don't think you can avoid the double-casting. You would benefit from a check before casting inside your foreach though:
`if(tuple is Tuple<string, bool>) { itemIds.Add(tuple as Tuple<string, bool>); }`

Comment: For the record this is upcasting. You need two casts because .net has runtime generics unlike java which has type erasure. You should NEVER use `as` cast without a null check. But most of all, WHY IS `myObject.ExtraData` an object?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach` can do second cast for you if you can't use `OfType` as suggested in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32061986/477420):

```
foreach (Tuple<string, bool> tuple in myObject.ExtraData as List<object>)
{
    itemIds.Add(tuple);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[IEnumerable.OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) can be used to only return objects of the specified `Type`.

```
using System.Linq;

var extra = (IEnumerable) myObject.ExtraData;
var itemIds = extra.OfType<Tuple<string, bool>>();

//do something with itemIds
```

The above code has the extra benefit of not wasting memory with another copy of the list.

Comment: Downvoting due to bad exception handling http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2013/09/19/casting-vs-quot-as-quot-embracing-exceptions/

Comment: My concern is that if `myObject.ExtraData` is a double, you get a `NullReferenceException` which is absurd!

Comment: Thanks @Aron, made a change

Comment: @RichardSchneider - What's the 'type' of `itemIds` in the code above? `IEnumerable` or `List<Tuple<,>>` or `IEnumerable<List<Tuple<,>>>`? It's the the last one, how could I use it as a drop-in replacement for the code that assumes `itemIds` is of type `List<Tuple<,>>`?

Comment: IEnumerable<Tuple<string, bool>>>

Comment: Strange. I don't get that. I get `IEnumerable<List<Tuple<,>>>`...I have to explicitly cast the itemIds to be able to use it as a List or even to iterate over in a `foreach` loop. Apparently, the `OfType` method is only filtering the IEnumerable but still returning content of type IEnumerable

Comment: `OfType<T>` is using deferred execution.  Just do `foreach (var tuple in itemIds)` and `tuple` will be a `Tuple<string,bool`>.